# WCF SSL configuration error perhaps

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, configuration, ssl

Trying to get HelloWorld working via SSL. Read all these docs:

1. [X509FindType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509findtype.aspx)
2. [How to: Use wsHttpBinding with Windows Authentication and Transport Security in WCF Calling from Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648431.aspx)
3. [How to: Configure a Port with an SSL Certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733791.aspx)
4. [How to: Create Temporary Certificates for Use During Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733813.aspx)
5. [Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) Screencasts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/wcf-screencasts.aspx)

All I know is that the certificate seems to be created and deployed correctly (both certificates, actually). Still, I guess something is wrong with my web.config (sorry, can't be more specific at this point). It's like there is no server listening on 443 or client expects an *http* instead of *https*. Can someone please point me to the appropriate resource and/or tell what am I doing wrong?

The web.config is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="HTTPBaseAddress" value=""/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" name="MyWCFServices.HelloWorldService">
        <clear />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mexEndpoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" listenUriMode="Explicit">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
            <certificateReference storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine" x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="SSLendpoint" contract="MyWCFServices.IHelloWorldService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
            <certificateReference x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" findValue="‎82a39faaeb18bf9585b334ca83264add3d5b26ee" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The client-side app.config is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="NoSecurity">
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
                <binding name="SSLsecurity">
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" /
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://localhost:443/HelloWorldSSL/HelloWorldService.svc"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IHelloWorldService"
                name="wsHttpBinding_IHelloWorldService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

If any additional info/screenshot is required - I'll happily provide it (as usual). Hope this is an answerable question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your configuration is not correct. You are not definining custom binding configuration in your endpoint so HTTPS is not used. Use this one for the server:

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="SSLSecurity">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors> 
  <serviceBehaviors> 
    <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" > 
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" /> 
    </behavior> 
  </serviceBehaviors> 
</behaviors> 
<services> 
  <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" 
    name="MyWCFServices.HelloWorldService"> 
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mexEndpoint" 
       contract="IMetadataExchange" listenUriMode="Explicit" /> 
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SSLSecurity" 
       name="SSLendpoint" contract="MyWCFServices.IHelloWorldService" /> 
  </service> 
</services>
```

For client use:

```
<bindings>   
  <wsHttpBinding>     
    <binding name="SSLSecurity">   
      <security mode="Transport">   
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />   
      </security>   
    </binding>   
  </wsHttpBinding>   
</bindings>   
<client>   
  <endpoint address="https://localhost:443/HelloWorldSSL/HelloWorldService.svc"    
     binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SSLSecurity"   
     contract="IHelloWorldService" name="wsHttpBinding_IHelloWorldService" />   
</client>
```

Comment: thank you - that solved some probs (with a few customizations). however, now receiving another error:  The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure. But on that, in the next my stackoverflow question :)